# How to add an key for parent::toArray in Laravel Resources

Tags: php, laravel

My code is;

```
$live_events = LiveEventContent::whereIn('parent_content_id',$contents_ids)->get();

foreach ($live_events as $live_event)
{
    //I will add an key called isStreamAvailable to the object
    $live_event->isStreamAvailable = true;
}

return LiveEventResource::collection($live_events);
```

and My Resource model;

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

I want to add isStreamAvailable key into the resource.

**How to edit the function in my resource model instead parent::toArray?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to returned value from parent:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $response = parent::toArray($request);

    $response['isStreamAvailable'] = true;

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you need to get value from your model.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}

public function with($request)
{
    return [
        'isStreamAvailable' => $this->isStreamAvailable()
    ];
}
```

Or adding data when constructing resources

```
return (new LiveEventResource($live_events)
                ->additional(['isStreamAvailable' => true]);
```

Comment: I have tried the 'with' function in my resource model, it didnt add the key into array